# Валидация ФИО на php

Tags: php, mysql

Привет. Такая проблема, при регистрации выходит **"ФИО не соответствует формату"**. Формат должен быть таким: **Иванов Иван Иванович**.
Код:

```
if( !empty($name) ){
    if(!preg_match("#^[А-Яа-яЁё]+\s[А-Яа-яЁё]+\s[А-Яа-яЁё]+$#i", $name)){
        $errors .= '<li><strong>ФИО</strong> не соответствует формату</li>';
    }
}
```

Что здесь не так? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Казалось бы причем тут email.

Answer (score 1):

Иванов Иван Иванович - это не адрес электронной почты. Пример адреса email - это example@email.com. Именно такой формат и проверяется в вашем регулярном выражении.

Comment: @Get, ой извиняюсь, спать уже пора, не то вставил, ( сейчас исправлю

Comment: В regexp все правильно, проверяйте содержимое $name

https://regex101.com/r/hM7bZ0/1

Comment: @Alextrue, можно немного улучшить regexp, добавив в него пробелы после окончания https://regex101.com/r/hM7bZ0/2